# Elasticsearch Shield Plugin - Users can not be authenticated, even users with Admin Privileges

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-shield

I'm having an issue with the Shield plugin for Elasticsearch. I have installed elasticsearch so that it runs as a service, and I can see that it is running on port 9200.

If I enter `curl http://localhost:9200` in my Mac terminal I get the correct elasticsearch output...

Recently I have been trying to upgrade from basic authentication to shield authentication. I installed shield and license using the following commands:

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install license/latest
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install shield/latest
```

This successfull installs shield and license plugins. They are contained within my /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins directory on my Vagrant box.

So, now if I try to use `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200` again, I get the following response:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing
>   authentication token for REST request
>   [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic
>   realm=\"shield\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing
>   authentication token for REST request
>   [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic
>   realm=\"shield\""}},"status":401}

This is good. I can not reach elasticsearch without proper authentication. So now I want to create a user to authenticate to elasticsearch. I use the command:

```
sudo ./esusers useradd testuser -p password -r admin
```

This creates a user 'testuser' with password 'password' with admin privileges.

I can verify that this user has been created using the following command:

```
sudo ./esusers list
```

This returns:

> testuser : admin

So I now try to run the curl command again with this user:

```
curl -u testuser:password -XGET http://localhost:9200
```

But I get the same error message as before when I tried without the admin user.

What is the issue here? Why is my admin user not authenticating?

Comment: This question didn't get an answer. I was using the elasticsearch/elasticsearch puppet module when I created this question, and I think it may have been causing my issues. I finally created my own elasticsearch puppet module, and my issues were resolved. I am sorry I can not provide any resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that your verified the user is created using `sudo ./esusers list` but still the curl command fails. Chances are that you are using custom directory for elasticsearch even though the home dir is `/usr/share/elasticsearch`. And due to this, the `esusers` creates the users in `/etc/elasticsearch/shield/` directory but they need to be copied to the custom dir, in case you are using one.

I know you've solved this differently but I'm answering this in the hope that it helps someone else in future. Can you confirm regarding the custom dir? For e.g in my case, the custom dir was `/data/elasticsearch` and the home dir was `/usr/share/elasticsearch`

Comment: This is potentially what was wrong. From what I remember, my elasticsearch directories were set up in a strange way when using the puppet forge module. I believe my cluster was given it's own directory, i.e /elasticsearch/es-01/. It's a little different from your example.

Comment: Hi @Xenidious, yes my directory differs because I've manually set custom directory `/data/elasticsearch`. In case one doesn't set that, then one gets what you mentioned `/etc/elasticsearch/es-01/`. Irrespective of that, I believe the shield directory needs to be copied from `/etc/elasticsearch/shield`. So in your case, it would need to be copied to `/etc/elasticsearch/es-01/` so that you will get `/etc/elasticsearch/es-01/shield`. Something like below:

    `rsync::get { '/etc/elasticsearch/es-01':
        source  => '/etc/elasticsearch/shield',
        purge   => true,
    }`